# how to set bash variable in expect or return variable from expect to bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
 VAR=$(expect -c ' 
 spawn ssh-copy-id -i '"$SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP"' 
 expect "*?assword:*" 
 send "'"$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD"'\r"; 
 expect {
 "Permission denied, please try again."{ 
 send user "Wrong pass" 
 exit 5
 }
 }
 ')
 echo "$VAR"
```

UPDATE:
So I need the exit condition when the code enters the Permission denied block.I am lookin at $?

But it is 0 because "$VAR" runs succesfully.

So I need a an integer return value when it enters Permission denied block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `VAR` contains the `output` of the command.

You have to use `$?`, which contains the exit status of the last command executed. Setting a variable doesn't alter `$?`, so it will still contain the exit status of the subshell `$(...)`.

Example:

```
x=$(expect -c 'send "hello"; exit 5;')
echo $?; echo $x
5
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Expect starts its own tcl shell, so you cannot use aliases defined in your bash environment.

Expect does have the variable `$env(YOURBASHVARIABLE)`, which allows Expect to grab your environment variables, but Expect can only modify them internal to the script.  However, any modifications you make to the variable will not be kept once the expect script is finished.

If flag is going to be a number, you could use an exit status (e.g., `exit 5`) and then use `$?` in your script to get the exit status.

**Per your update**
The expect script doesn't return anything, it just sets an exit code.

What you could do is simply:

```
$(expect -c ' 
  spawn ssh-copy-id -i '"$SSH_KEY_PATH_PUB $REMOTE_HOST_USER@$REMOTE_HOST_IP"' 
  expect "*?assword:*" 
  send "'"$REMOTE_HOST_PASSWD"'\r"; 
  expect {
    "Permission denied, please try again."{ 
      send user "Wrong pass" 
      exit 5
    }
  }
'); var=$?
```

This way, `var` will be set to your exit status.

Also, you should take note of this:

> By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and
>   internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully
>   capitalized. All other variable names should have at least one
>   lowercase letter. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this
>   convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal
>   variables.

EDIT(mpapis): there is also other use case:

```
if output="$(expect ...)"
then
  echo "it worked: $output"
else
  result=$?
  echo "it failed($result): $output"
fi
```

**EDIT(twmb)**

With the last use case, you have to be careful with what you are returning.  It will take all output sent to the user.  Unless you have logging turned off (with `log_user 0`) and you are controlling exactly what will be outputted in the expect script, you will probably get more information than needed.

Another drag with this is indicated in the comment below;

```
returned="$(expect -c '
  log_user 1  ;# turn to 0 and use send_user to control the exact output
  spawn bash
  expect "\\$"
  send "echo hello\r"
  send_user "this will be returned"
  expect "\\$" ;# without this line, the script would exit too fast 
               ;# for the "echo hello" to be sent to stdout by bash
               ;# and thus wont be recorded
  exit 6
  '
  )"; var=$?
echo "var: $var"
echo "returned: $returned"
```

Comment: @twmb.I tried to give exit status as exit 5. but when I run the command "$VAR", it is run and $? will give exit status of VAR, so it is 0. isnt it?.how can I handle the exit value. this is the absolute think I want

Comment: Can you update your code so I can see what you are doing now?

Comment: I can not try now but your and Stephane's solution seems good as setting flag with as env in my script

Answer (score 0):

In expect you can use `set env` to manipulate environment variables.
If a number, you can pass variable from expect to bash thanx to exit command.
Let's see an example:

```
~/Desktop> cat test.exp
puts "From shell: FLAG=$env(FLAG)"
set env(FLAG) 22
puts "Set by expect: FLAG=$env(FLAG)"
exit $env(FLAG)
~/Desktop> export FLAG=0
~/Desktop> expect test.exp 
From shell: FLAG=0
Set by expect: FLAG=22
~/Desktop> echo $?
22
~/Desktop>
```